# Persistent volume isn't matched with a claim

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I created a simple local storage volume. Something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: vol1
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /srv/volumes/vol1
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - my-node
```

The I create a claim:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  resources:
    requests:
      storage:1Gi
```

For unknow reason they don't get matches. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed a user. As long as I had a user, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

About local storage it is worth to note that:

> Using local storage ties your application to that specific node,
>   making your application harder to schedule. If that node or local
>   volume encounters a failure and becomes inaccessible, then that pod
>   also becomes inaccessible. In addition, many cloud providers do not
>   provide extensive data durability guarantees for local storage, so you
>   could lose all your data in certain scenarios.

This is for Kubernetes [1.10](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/). In Kubernetes [1.14](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/04/04/kubernetes-1.14-local-persistent-volumes-ga/) local persistent volumes became GA.

You posted an answer that user is required. Just to clarify the user you meant is a consumer like a pod, deployment, statefullset etc. 
So using just a simple pod definition would make your PV to become bound:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myfrontend
      image: nginx
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/var/www/html"
        name: mypd
  volumes:
    - name: mypd
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myclaim
```

Now the problem happens when you would delete the pod and try to run another one. In this case if you or someone else wold look for a solution it has been described in this [GitHub issue](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48609%23issuecomment-314066616&sa=D&source=hangouts&ust=1556362801325000&usg=AFQjCNEpCZR29ayWUmDt7-x0e5ZuGnG82A).

Hope this clears things out.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify `volumeName` in your PVC to bind that specifically to the PV that you just created as so:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myclaim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeName: "vol1"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage:1Gi
```

Additionally, if you specify `storageClassName` in your PVC, your PVC will also get bound to a PV matching that specification (though it doesn't guarantee that it will be bound to your "vol1" PV if there are more than 1 PVs for that storage class).

Hope this helps!